# reduce table row space and also adjust it to one column in two column format

Tags: tables

I am using ieee format and working on overleaf two column format. I tried this table and now i want to reduce this table space and make it narrow and also want to fit it to one column . .

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makecell}%
%table
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{times}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}
\makeatother

%\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{4}{c} @{}}
\toprule
ooooooooo& bbbbbb 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccvvvvvv} 
  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ccccccccc}\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}  
 & & \makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell{vvvvvvvvv\\ (vvvvvvv)}  &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv\\ (cccc)} &\makecell {vvvvvvvvv \\ (vvvvvvvv)} \\




\midrule
vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv & bbbbbbbbb  &fff &fffffffff   &fffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffff &  fffffff8 &fff  &fffffffffffff  & ff &fffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffffff & ffffffffff     &fff &ffffffffff   & ffff &ffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  & fffff &fff &fffffffffffff  &fff &fffffffffffff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffff     &fff &ffffffffffff4  &ffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff & fffffff &fffffff &fffffffff  &ffffffffffffff& ff \\
\addlinespace %\midrule
fffffffff  &  ffffffff &fff &ffff   &fffffffffffff& ff\\
\addlinespace %\midrule
ffffffffffffffff  & ffffffffff &8fffff &ffffffffffff  &ffff& fffffffffffff\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why would you ever do `\newcommand{\removelatexerror}{\let\@latex@error\@gobble}` ?????????????

Comment: in general `\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}` probably works (after changing `table*` to `table` to get 1-column) but usually reformatting the data is better than making it as smal as `\tiny` but impossible to suggest anything with fake table data as it depends on the context.

Comment: the fake data is similar length to orignal one

Comment: sure so you can probably use `\tiny` (as that works on the supplied example) but it is usually better to _rearrange_ the data to make a taller thinner table and that can only be done with real data (or at least real headings) and some domain knowledge to know a sensible re-arrangement.